using the package of natbib moves the bibliography into a preceding section
I am trying to use the latex template provided at https://gradschool.utah.edu/thesis/templates-guides-samples/index.php. The file I am compiling is sample-thesis-0.tex and I am compiling it on Overleaf.
I ran into this super weird problem: If I use the natbib package by adding the line \usepackage{natbib} at row 82,the bibliography section will be moved into the preceding section (e.g., the appendix section in this case).
For example, the picture below shows how the bibliography section looks before I added the package

And the picture below shows how it looks after I added the package.

Anyone knows why natbib causes this, or how to fix this if I have to use natbib?

Please add a compilable [mre] to your question

I have exactly the same issue. Have you already figured it out?
